# Re-size Array (like expanding and image) - Java

Tags: java, arrays, expand, image-resizing

Sorry let me rephrase the question, 
I need to figure out how to move each element of the array into the new array: like for the "x" position of each element would be moved to "x*2" and "x*2+1": so array[0] -> array2[0], array2[1] and array[1] -> array2[2], array2[3] etc. but for the "y" value also

For my Java application I need a function that inputs

```
   [[1,0,1],
    [1,0,1],
    [1,1,1]]
```

And would replicate the array and output

```
   [[1,1,0,0,1,1],
    [1,1,0,0,1,1],
    [1,1,0,0,1,1], 
    [1,1,0,0,1,1],
    [1,1,1,1,1,1],
    [1,1,1,1,1,1]]
```

here is what I can figure out

```
public short[][] expandArray(short[][] arr) {
   short[][] newArray = new short[arr.length*2][arr[0].length*2];
   for(int s=0; s<arr.length; s++)
      for(int ss=0; ss<arr[0].length; ss++) {
         newArray[s*2][(new corresponding row)] = arr[s][ss];
         newArray[s*2+1][(new corresponding row)] = arr[s][ss];

         newArray[s*2][(next row down)] = arr[s][ss];
         newArray[s*2+1][(next row down)] = arr[s][ss];
      }
   return newArray;
}
```

My goal is to duplicate each element in the array to the right and down

EX:
OriginalArray[0][0] 
would be put into 
NewArray[0][0], NewArray[0][1], NewArray[1][0], NewArray[1][1]

Thanks

Comment: What do you have so far? Can you show us some code? Where exactly are you having trouble?

Comment: Could you provide the code that you tried? So that we can help you in debugging any issue in it.

Comment: @theone15247 The way your question is put right now, it appears you are asking StackOverflow to write code _for_ you. All you've posted is your goal and are asking "how do I accomplish this?". You should make an effort to write the code yourself, or if you have already done this, show us that you have. The goal of SO is to help people learn, not to help them (directly) get their work done. Just giving you the code - although there are hundreds if not thousands of people here who could - would run counter to this objective.

Comment: @Borealid He has posted the code.

Comment: Quickly wrote out the code I could figure out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int[][] array = { {1,0,1}, {1,0,1}, {1,1,1} };
        int[][] newArray = replicate(array);

        int i = 1;

        System.out.print("[ ");
        for(int[] a : newArray)
        {
            System.out.print(Arrays.toString(a) + (i++ != newArray.length? ", " : "") );
        }
        System.out.println(" ]");
    }

    public static int[][] replicate(int[][] array)
    {
        int x = array.length;
        int y = array[0].length;

        int counterX = 0;
        int counterY = 0;

        int[][] newArray = new int[2 * x][2 * y];
        for(int[] a : array)
        {
            for(int b : a)
            {
                newArray[counterX++][counterY] = b;
                newArray[counterX--][counterY++] = b;

                newArray[counterX++][counterY] = b;
                newArray[counterX--][counterY++] = b;
            }
            counterY = 0;
            counterX++;
            counterX++;
        }

        return newArray;
    }
}
```

**output:**

```
[ [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1] ]
```